# "functions start" starts wrong functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I run `firebase serve` in my functions directory, my functions get served fine. But when I run `functions start`, it runs some other function that I worked on a long time ago. How does it decide what to start? Shouldn't it start the function of the directory I'm in?

I also running the following:

> functions config set projectId [my-project-on-firebase]

and

> firebase use [my-project-on-firebase]

But still getting the same results

[image: f]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `firebase` command is part of the Firebase CLI, which is provided by Firebase to emulate your functions that would be deployed with the CLI.  It's different than the [Google Cloud Functions Emulator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/functions-emulator) which is run with the `functions` command.  They generally don't have anything to do with each other.  You use the Firebase tools if you're going to deploy with the Firebase CLI, and you use Cloud tools if you're going to deploy with gcloud.  You don't use them in tandem with each other, and they have different configurations.  So, when you run each command, you're going to get a different configuration.  You'll have to go back and figure out how you configured the Cloud tools to be different from the Firebase tools.